# Using python library for GIST feature extraction on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, python-2.7, gist

I just started using Python (version 2.7.2) on Windows 7.
I want to use GIST feature in my python project. I have been looking around for the GIST python library. There is a famous library called pyleargist (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyleargist/1.0.1#downloads).

However, I have tried so many ways to build and install this library on Windows7. Unfortunately, it didn't success at all. Therefore, I would like to ask 2 questions here.

1. Is there any other alternative python library (apart from pyleargist or writing it myself) for GIST image descriptor?
2. Have any of you ever been able to use pyleargist library for any Python 2.7 code on Windows7?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried building pyleargist on *nix system?